# PHP module uploadprogress installed but can't be detected

Tags: php, upload, progress-bar

Hey all. I've successfully installed the php extension uploadprogress on my 1and1 acct. You can verify at [www.mgxvideo.com/info.php](http://www.mgxcopy.com/info.php). Using code I got [from this site](http://stuff.harperreed.org/?path=code%2Fphp_upload_progressbar), I get the following error:

> ```
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function uploadprogress_get_info()
> ```

Basically, you can view my code at [progress.txt](http://www.mgxvideo.com/mgxcopy-dev/php_upload_progressbar/progress.txt) and [upload.txt](http://www.mgxvideo.com/mgxcopy-dev/php_upload_progressbar/upload.txt). I've spent all night trying to get this jquery upload progress indicator working. As always, any and all help and ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you're just looking for a way to display an upload progress meter there are various libraries that use a combination ofJavaScript and Flash to achieve this entirely on the client-side without any messing with the server.

Check out [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/), and [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/). I've used FancyUpload a fair bit myself, but it's built with the Mootools framework and so may not be your thing if you're using jQuery. I'm sure jQuery alternatives won't be too far away in Google land though.

(Apologies if you know all this already and there's some special reason you need to use the PHP extension.)